# Phonegap prevent scrolling when show keyboard

Tags: ios, cordova

On Phonegap application, is there any way to prevent page scrolling  when a text-input is focused and the soft keyboard shows?
In case of no way, Is there any way to scroll the page to the position of text input instead of 'bring' the text input onto center of screen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in phonegap 2.6 there is a new option to prevent scrolling by resizing the webview. take a look at the [documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.6.0/guide_project-settings_ios_index.md.html#Project%20Settings%20for%20iOS) and find the `KeyboardShrinksView` option.

cheers

Answer (score 0):

I've used this javascript code with some success.  It overrides the window.scrollTo function and cancels it out...

```
window.oldScrollTo = window.scrollTo;

window.scrollTo = function (x, y) {

    console.log("window.scrollTo");
    return;
};
```